# Is there a way for my swift app to link to the app-store and pass through information to the app if the person who uses the link downloads the app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I'd like to invite someone to my app.  The invitation would include a link to the app in the appstore.  If they download the app, I'd like the person who sent the invitation to have their information passed through, so the app can know that they are "friends/contacts".  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

if it is beta testing use testflight. public storefront use link to App store